# What is the downloadUrl property in a File object of the drive rest api?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am working on a project where I'd like to upload a file to a Google Drive using a URL. One property I stumbled upon was `downloadUrl`. I'm not sure if it's what I need yet, but in the documentation here (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) the column of description is blank.

[image]

What is this property used for?

Comment: (Going on context clues so I'm not going to do a real answer) It seems like the URL that an app would point a new chrome tab to in order to initiate a download. It probably begins with HTTPS (behind Drive authentication) and ends with a file type like .pdf or .csv

Comment: So similar to how a link would work to initiate a download?

Comment: Ya exactly. But like I said, just a guess

Answer (score 2):

This property is used to allow you to download the file. If it is present in the file info metadata you can use it to issue a HTTP GET request and download the file.

You can do it using a token granted by the domain administrator user or the file's owner user.

Answer (score 1):

'downloadUrl' Allows you to download files that are stored in Google Drive. You can download Google Documents and export them in a few different formats using exportLinks .

To get downloadUrls, you need to get the  [metadata of a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource-representations). Do it by requesting  [**GET**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) method. The method will return a file resource that include '*downloadUrl*' property.